# Active directory list of users and "member of" from trusted domain

Tags: security, active-directory, users, groups

I've been trying to create a csv file of all the members of an AD but since some groups have members from another trusted domain, these users are not showing up. I also tried outputting users in a text file by using:

```
dsquery group -name "Group Account Name" | dsget group -members -expand > C:users.txt
```

and failing. Does someone know if what I'm trying to do is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your Dsquery syntax is missing the domain root LDAP path.  It should look like:

```
dsquery group "DC=contoso,DC=com" -name "group name" | dsget group -members -expand > C:\Users.txt
```

Try with the updated syntax.

As per sysadmin1138's suggestion, here would be the command sent to a variable array "$members":

```
$members = (dsquery group "DC=contoso,DC=com" -name "group name" | dsget group -members -expand)
```

Comment: I tried pasting the script that I am using but it won't let me since its too big to show here. Basically I am using Powershell and the command is = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * etc.. Can I use dsquery instead?

Comment: By the way your syntax worked perfectly. But we have a lot of groups, is it possible with the script I got from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381943/how-to-export-csv-of-active-directory-objects  ?

Comment: @JoshuaVella In my experience dsquery is a *lot* faster than native PowerShell utilities for doing mass enumeration. What's better, is that dsquery can pass things into PowerShell datastructures very cleanly. Do the above and instead of piping to a file, send to a variable and you'll get an array.

Answer (score 0):

"all the members of an **AD**" - Should that be "**AD group**"?

If so, using the Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell, you could issue the following command:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Group Account Name" | out-file users.txt
```

If you'd like to get all members of all groups (per your comment), do the following:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Get-ADGroupMember | Where{$_.objectClass -eq "user"} | select * -unique | out-file users.txt
```

If you need to recurse through nested groups, add the -recursive switch to the GetADGroupMember cmdlet.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear sorry. We have 2 domains in a trust relationship. I am trying to "get member of" each user from the local domain but the thing is, the groups are on the other domain where I am running the script. If I run the script on the local one, it does not show the groups for the users.

Comment: Your syntax worked. Is it possible to create the list for all the groups and not specifying a group yourself?